# Requirements to prove the Markov property in a DAG

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, graphical-model, dag

Suppose that I have the following PDFs well-defined: 
$$
f_A(A), f_B(B|A), f_C(C|B,D), f_D(D)
$$
From these PDFs I can deduce the following direct dependence relation:
$$
A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \leftarrow D
$$
Given the above, on what grounds can I be sure that the joint probability function is correctly written as:
$$
f(A,B,C,D)=f_A(A)f_B(B|A)f_C(C|B,D)f_D(D)
$$
and not in some other way.

Note that usually the Markov property of a DAG is assumed from which follows that the joint probability can be decomposed as above. The question here is backwards. I have the partial probabilities (from which I can construct the above DAG), and I want to prove that what I have meets the Markov property.

Once I am sure that the joint probability can be written as above, I can use the theory.

Comment: @Taylor, I understand that the Markov property is equivalent to the last equality. I want to prove the last equality, and thus the Markov property. I wonder if what I have is enough for the proof. No need to test the assumption empirically.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \leftarrow D$ from your PDFs alone. You also need independence assumptions such as, in your case $(C|B) \perp A$ that cannot be deduced from the densities you mentioned. Except maybe if you consider that the model is fully defined by these densities, which is equivalent to implicitly defining independences and which is, IMHO, an error-prone solution.

Elucidating and using these hidden independences, it is likely that you could  factorize the $f(A,B,C,D)$ as in your last equation.

Comment: It should be $C \perp A \;| \; B$. Why can I not deduce this?